# How to get zonal stats only for fully covered pixels in Python

Tags: python, zonal-statistics

I want to get the statics of raster values per polygon in a shape file in Python.

Currently I use: https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/.

But as I understand it has two raster stategies:

- all_touched=True: Takes all pixels that are somehow covered by the
  polygon
- all_touched_False: Take all pixels, with the pixel centre covered by
  the polygon.

What I am looking for is a strategy, that only selects pixels that are covered FULLY covered by the polygon.

What I currently do, is to buffer the polygons with a negative buffer, which is somewhat unprecise. Is there a better strategy to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this makes sense, but if "all-touched minus the resulting edge pixels" meets your definition of "fully covered", you could possibly monkeypatch [`rasterize_geom()`](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/blob/aa4130e2ea03c9227b6793b7fe94adb9485bcb58/src/rasterstats/utils.py#L28) to perform a [binary erosion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) of the raster mask

Comment: Thanks for you answer, when understand your idea correctly, I think binary erosion would shrink the object possibly slightly  to much?

Comment: That might take some experimentation to find out.  I imagine using a 3x3 square or a 3x3 "+" shape as the structuring element could potentially do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This question does not specify a GIS system so here is a solution using ArcMap. A simple sequence of tools which could be captured as a model can generate the required results.

[image: Model]

The output  (rasInnerPixels) would look as below in this sample data:

[image: Results]

**Update: an alternative approach**

As spotted by @alphabetasoup the approach above is sub-optimal missing cells due to an edge effect when rasterizing the polygon; below is an alternative approach that uses the initial raster mask as a template for creating a polygon grid with the same cell size as the DEM, often known as a fishnet. Cells of this net are deleted out initially if they fall outside the polygon, then a second deletion occurs for cells intersecting the polygon boundary (the boundary is created by turning the polygon into a line feature). This leaves only cells that are fully within the polygon. The final step is to use this subset of polygon cells as a mask to extract out the relevant pixels from the DEM.

*Click on model to enlarge*

[image: Model]

Final results:

[image: Correct results]

*As a side note, for people who like to optimise things, if the first spatial selection method had Intersect replaced with Completely within source layer you could drop out 3 subsequent steps (tools) from the model!*

Comment: Why does it appear that there are a number of pixels that are fully within the polygon but are not included?

Comment: @alphabetasoup - Well spotted! I missed those. I believe the issue is down to the step of converting the polygon to its raster equivalent. The edge of the polygon sometimes _just_ clips a cells and I think they get excluded from the rasterization step and thus the use of the shrink tool ends up excluding some of the pixels.  I guess I can say this method guarantees cells within the polygon but is a sub-optimal solution as, as you noted, it misses some due to an edge effect.

Comment: I wondered if it was the raster shrink. What would happen if you buffered the original input by the cell resolution (assuming x and y resolution is equal), take its outer boundary, and then use the original approach? Then there's the complexity of holes and overlapping multi-geometries...